# How to select the result between two numbers range?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

I need to select the result based on the column `col1` value.
`col1,col2` is text field type.

```
 +-----+-----------+------+
 | id  |    col1   | col2 |
 +-----+-----------+------+
 | 1   | 1200-1220 | XXX  |
 +-----+-----------+------+
 | 2   | 1455-1460 | YYY  |
 +-----+-----------+------+
```

Example query:

```
SELECT col2 FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE col1 = 1215
```

Result i want:

> 'XXX'

How I get the above result.

If I inserted wrong, in which format I need to insert a row to get the result.

Please advise.

Comment: That is an unfortunate way to design your table schema.

Comment: Yes..I've to insert more record,thats why i am using this table design.I got solution by @Gordan answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This takes a bit of manipulation but it is possible in MySQL:

```
where 1215 between substring_index(col1, '-', 1) + 0 and substring_index(col1, '-', -1) + 0
```

That is, the field is parsed into the first and last values (which are then converted to number).

Comment: Great..!@Gordon You are save my hours

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test2` (
  `id` char(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col1` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `col2` varchar(90) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `test2` (`id`, `col1`, `col2`) VALUES
('1', '1200-1220', 'XXX'),
('2', '1455-1460', 'YYY');
```

> Query:

```
SELECT col2 FROM test2 WHERE 1215 BETWEEN 
   CONVERT(SUBSTRING(col1, 1, LOCATE('-',col1) - 1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) AND
   CONVERT(SUBSTRING(col1, LOCATE('-',col1) + 1),UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```